# Custom display of JScrollPane's actual scroll bars (make transparent)

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, alpha-transparency, jscrollbar

I have a text area with a `JScrollPane` and am tailoring the display with things like;

```
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    text.setOpaque(false);
    text.setFont(...);
    text.setForeground(Color.white);
    text.setBackground(Color.black);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
    scroll.setOpaque(false);
    scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
```

and the scroll and text area are showing as transparent (non-opaque), however, I can't seem to affect the actual scroll bars. **They still appear as the default grey color** where I'd like to change their color and/or make them transparent to match the rest.

I've tried things like

```
     scroll.setBackground(Color.black);
     scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setOpaque(false);
```

but it doesn't make any difference.

**What's the preferred way to do a custom display for the scroll bars?**

Comment: not possible in the general case: how/if/what exactly is painted as background is highly LAF dependend, f.i. Metal accepts the transparent, Win doesn't at all. Nothing you can do, short of trying to extend the LAF (as @mKorbel already suggested)

Answer (score 1):

> and the scroll and text area are showing as transparent (non-opaque),
>   however, I can't seem to affect the actual scroll bars. They still
>   appear as the default grey color where I'd like to change their color
>   and/or make them transparent to match the rest.

there are two ways

- you would need to override `BasicScrollBarUI()`,
- without any [commnets milion dollars baby by @aterai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375805/714968),
- there is `VerticalScrollBar` only, you need to override and add `HorizontalScrollBar`, to `ScrollPaneLayout()` that returns coordinated for `Horizontal JScrollBar`,

Comment: I've struggled finding out more about overriding UI classes (like BasicScrollBarUI). Any pointers to better reading or could you extend the answer a little?