# JFrame: how to make Transparent Scollbar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I was working on some code for the last couple hours trying to make the scrollbar transparent.  I ' been able to make it transparent when i grab the scrollbar object from the scroll-pane and change its value.

any other way to do this?

[JFrame Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StkrP.jpg)

Comment: Don't put code in an image! Paste it as text in an [edit] to the question. Further tips: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't think they are transparent, but are simply the same color as the editor

Answer (score 0):

Extend `javax.swing.JViewPort`. You can paint anything inside it

```
class TransparentViewPort extends JViewport
{

    public TransparentViewPort() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

}
```

Then set an instance of TransparentViewPort as your JScrollPane's view port:

```
scrollPane.setViewport(new TransparentViewPort())
```

And if you want to make JScrollBar transparent look at [Java JScrollBar Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373459/java-jscrollbar-design/16375805#16375805)

Comment: I Tried this and it just makes my Scrollpane disappear, am i doing something wrong?